# Estimating population size from capture recapture metho

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Given a population of unknown size, with k tagged individuals, we sample n of them and find m to be tagged. We would like an estimate for the size of the population N
If we assume equal likelyhood of capture throughout and constant population size, we can apply the Lincoln-Petersen method and estimate N using the ratio: $kn/m$, I would like to formally derive this ratio by maximizing the discrete probability function of tagged indvidualsin the sample. i.e. find N such that the probability of having m tagged individuals in our sample of size n is maximized.

We know that P(m out of n individuals are tagged)=${k\choose m}{N-k\choose n-n}/{N\choose n}$.
I would like to show that the ratio / is the value of N that maximizes this function but I/m getting stuck in the computation.

Comment: I did not know that $N_0=kn/m$ is the max likelihood estimate, so I ran some numerical tests.  As far as my tests show, it is indeed the MLE but I found a curious thing: $N_1 = (kn/m)-1$ is just as likely!  I.e. both $N_0$ and $N_1$ result in the same maximum value for $P()$.  Now of course, numerical testing $\neq$ proof, but this is very very interesting...

Comment: One difficulty with L-P method is that $E(\hat N) = kn/m$ does not exist, because there a possibility that $m = 0.$ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) for slightly different Chapman estimator. [Wikipedia's notation is sensible, but take care to note differences from yours.]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210550/find-an-estimator-of-n-hypergeometric

Comment: @antkam Probably you tested keeping $kn/m$ an integer, in which case indeed $N_0,N_1$ are both MLEs. If not, we take $\lfloor N_0 \rfloor$ as unique MLE.