# There are N fish in a pond

Tags: probability, combinatorics, maximum-likelihood

There are N fish in a pond. You use a net to catch them, and each fish is equally likely to be caught.
One day, you catch 40 fish, tag each of them, and then throw them back. The next day, you catch 30 fish in the net and note that 6 have tags.

**What is your best guess of the value of N?**

I think this relates to the capture - recapture problem where N= total population; n=first sample, k=tagged items, m=second sample.

$\frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{m-k}}{\binom{N}{m}}$

but I honestly do not know how to proceed.

Comment: The pertinent equation for the best-guess value is simpler: It's just $6/30=40/N$. (Of course this only works because the result turns out to be an integer.)

Comment: It may depend on what counts as "best".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206178/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683583/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210550/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3809554/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple:

> on Day 1 proportion of fish in pond that are tagged $=\frac{40}{N}$

> on Day 2 proportion of fish in sample that are tagged $=\frac{6}{30}$

> so solve $\frac{40}{N}$ = $\frac{6}{30}$ to get N = 200

Comment: setting sample ratio equal to population ratio. Then that would be the "most likely" population value?  What kind of distribution therefrom, if each fish has equal likelihood (i.e. uniform confidence?)? binomial?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, we need to use the capture-recapture formula, but this does not involve combinatorics. Here is the formula below: $$N=\frac{1st\:sample\:\times\:2nd\:sample}{2nd\:sample\:previously\:marked}$$ So in this case, $N =(40×30)/6=1200/6=200 $

Comment: What would you do if the calculated value was not an integer, e.g., if the first sample had been $39$ fish caught instead of $40$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Then you would round the calculated value up.

Comment: Why up and not down?

Answer (score 0):

Define a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 64}\rightarrow [0,1]$ by $f(n)=\frac{{40 \choose 6}{n-40 \choose 24}}{{n \choose 30}}$. Then $f(n)=P(X=6|N=n)$ where $X$ is the number of tagged fish in your second sample of $30$ fish. I would use the value of $n$ that maximizes $f(n)$ as my estimate for $N$.

Comment: That maximum likelihood estimator seems to give $199$ or $200$, similar to MathGeek's natural estimator

Comment: How can a find such value N with a simple calculator?

Comment: @Marco It may be easier to find the max of $\ln(f(x))$ on Desmos.