# Find the best N

Tags: probability

Imagine you have an urn of $N$ balls with $n$ white balls and $N-n$ black balls. we pick $n$ random balls from this urn. if $n,k$ are fixed numbers, then find the best $N$ such that maximizes the probability of the fact that there exists exactly $k$ white balls between these $n$ selected balls.

I think the probability that we want to maximize is equal to:

$\frac{{{n}\choose{k}}{{N-n}\choose{n-k}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}}$

but I do not know for which $N$ this maximizes?!

Comment: You could call $u_N=\frac{{{n}\choose{k}}{{N-n}\choose{n-k}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}}$, and study $\frac{u_{N+1}}{u_N}$...

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS yes, but the result is not simple enough to find the best N(at least it is not clear for me)

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210550/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206178/321264.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken : let $u_N=\frac{{{n}\choose{k}}{{N-n}\choose{n-k}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}}$. Then
$$\frac{u_{N+1}}{u_N} = \frac{(N+1-n)^2}{(N+1)(N+1-2n+k)}$$
so
$$\frac{u_{N+1}}{u_N} - 1 = \frac{-kN+n^2-k}{(N+1)(N+1-2n+k)}$$
This number is non negative (*i.e.* $u_{N+1}>u_N$) if and only if
$$-kN+n^2-k\geq 0 \iff N \leq \frac{n^2-k}{k} = A$$
So the optimal $N$ is $\lceil A+1\rceil$ (there may be $2$ optimal $N$ if $A$ is an integer).

Hope I didn't make mistakes.