# How many fish are there in the pond?

Tags: probability, statistics

We want to estimate the $N=\text{#number of fish in a pond}$

We catch r fish and mark them and then set them all free

We the catch n fish, of which X, are marked

(r,n constants we determine and X is an observation)

How many fish are there in the pond?

---

I was advised to first find the probability of $X=3$ with r=10 and n=5 but as I have no background in probability I don't know exactly how to do this. Any help?

Comment: This is a classical method in statistics called catch-recatch or mark-recapture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture

Comment: Relevant threads: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3210550/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206178/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mark-recapture method of estimating population size.**

***Assumptions.***  You assume that the pond (population) has been *stable* between between (a) the time when $r$ fish out of a total of $N$ in the pond are captured and marked and (b) the later time when $n$ fish are captured, of which $X$ are marked (re-captured). That is, there have been no births or deaths and no immigration or emigration. You also assume that between times (a) and (b) the fish swim randomly around the pond, so that marking and recapturing are both random.

***Estimate.*** Thus you should have $\frac{n}{N} \approx \frac{X}{r}$ [the proportion of marked fish in the lake is about the same as the proportion of marked fish in the sample at time (b)].
Therefore, $N \approx \frac{nr}{X}.$

For the specific numbers suggested in your Question, that's $N \approx \frac{5(10)}{3}$ which rounds down to $N \approx 16$ fish in the pond.

***Hypergeometric distribution.*** The random number $X$ of marked fish recaptured, given $r$ marked fish in the pond, $n$ fish
caught at time (b) and $N$ total fish in the pond, is a hypergeometric probability. Using the suggested values and $N = 16$ above this is

$$P(X = 3) = \frac{{r\choose x}{N-r \choose n-3}}{{N\choose n}}
= \frac{{10\choose 3}{16-10 \choose 5-3}}{{16\choose 5}} = 0.4121.$$

Using the hypergeometric PDF function `dhyper` in R, this is computed as follows:

```
dhyper(3, 10,16-10, 5)
[1] 0.4120879
choose(10,3)*choose(6,2)/choose(16,5)
[1] 0.4120879
```

***Maximizing likelihood.*** Given $n = 5, r = 10$ as suggested, what
value of $N$ gives the largest value of $P(X=3)?$
Looking among values of $N$ from $10$ through $25,$ an easy computation in R shows the answer to be $N = 16.$ (Ignore row numbers in brackets `[ ]`.)

```
N = 10:25;  r = 10;  n = 5
p = dhyper(3,  r, N-r,  n)
cbind(N, round(p,4))
       N       
 [1,] 10 0.0000
 [2,] 11 0.0000
 [3,] 12 0.1515
 [4,] 13 0.2797
 [5,] 14 0.3596
 [6,] 15 0.3996
 [7,] 16 0.4121  # <- LARGEST
 [8,] 17 0.4072
 [9,] 18 0.3922
[10,] 19 0.3715
[11,] 20 0.3483
[12,] 21 0.3243
[13,] 22 0.3008
[14,] 23 0.2782
[15,] 24 0.2569
[16,] 25 0.2372
```

*Note:* A difficulty with this method of estimation comes from the possibility
that the number $X$ of marked fish that are recaptured could be $X = 0,$ giving an absurd infinite estimate for $N.$

Thus it is not realistic to talk about $E(N)$ or to ask whether this expectation is close to $N.$ If you will look at the Wikipedia article linked by @YJT, you will find a slightly altered Chapman estimator of $N$ that does not have this difficulty.

Comment: I have not been taught the Hypergeometric distribution. How exactly do you explain the usage of it? Furthermore, I am unclear about the total estimation for N

Comment: Sort of like binomial except sampling is without replacement, making trials somewhat dependent. Typical problem: An urn has 10 red marbles and 5 blue ones, withdraw 4 marbles without replacement, what is probability of getting 2 red and 2 blue? Ans: ${10\choose 2}{5\choose 2}/{15\choose 4}.$ In R `dhyper(2, 10,5, 4)`. 
 [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).